# windbg, .net 4, random access violation, unable to get a managed stack trace

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windbg, access-violation, managed

I have a really weird problem and am trying to track it down. An Access_Violation in .Net4. Here's a little background info on things I personally think that could be causing the exception.

1) I have a process that monitors for a file, takes the file and dumps it into a database using SqlBulkCopy in .net.

2) Then, it goes through the file records that are in the database, marking them as processed when they are done, each group of records gets handled in multiple threads as it could take a while for each group. Once the group is handled, it markes those records in the group processed through a stored procedure.
2a) The processing of those groups is where it uses SqlBulkCopy and creates a bunch of other records used to create notifications to be sent out. There's a bunch of data that gets added/converted and as such, I have found that SqlBulkCopy is by far the fastest way, otherwise it just takes to long to put that much data into a database using EntityFramework.

3)In the thread that creates the notifications from a succesfully generated notice data, it can encrypt some of the data before the notice is created.

4) Old data is removed from the database.

Note: My code uses standard .Net4 libraries and no unmanaged calls.

These processes are all run under a Windows Service running as a System User.
And I've tried to be as verbose as possible in describing my problem, as there doesn't seem to be anybody with anything like this issue.

Here's the things I have tried that have not succeeded.
1) Run the service as a Console App.
2) Change the processing of a file into a single thread instead of many.
3) Locking an object so as to prevent multiple SqlBulkCopies at the same time.
4) Attaching WinDbg to the process to attempt to capture the exception and figure out where it is crashing (I couldn't catch it). I tried using WinDbg because it looks like it was supposed to catch the exception....It didn't, maybe I missed loading some module, or telling to catch/ignore a certain exception

Here is my WinDbg commands (bolded) and their output. I don't know much about WinDbg, so it was all just shooting in the dark.

Thanks in advance for all your help,
-Ed-

```
*This was done right after the service started so I could load the modules and ignore the first chance Access_Violation method*
(fd8.11bc): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
00000000`77310530 cc              int     3
0:014> **sxd av**
0:014> **.loadby sos clr**
0:014> **.load c:\debugstuff\psscor4.dll**
0:014> **g**
(fd8.c18): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
00000000`77310530 cc              int     3
0:006> **.reload**
Reloading current modules
................................................................
......................
0:006> **g**
(fd8.e24): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xa:
00000000`773115da c3              ret
0:009> **!clr**
No export clr found
0:009> **!clrstack**
OS Thread Id: 0xe24 (9)
Unable to walk the managed stack. The current thread is likely not a 
managed thread. You can run !threads to get a list of managed threads in
the process
0:009> **!threads**
ThreadCount:      10
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 9
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       0
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                           PreEmptive                                                   Lock
       ID  OSID        ThreadOBJ     State GC       GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count APT Exception
XXXX    1   d10 000000000057ca00      a020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005659c0     0 MTA
XXXX    2  149c 0000000000582d40      b220 Enabled  00000000040ce9a0:00000000040d0958 00000000005659c0     0 MTA (Finalizer)
XXXX    3  1294 00000000005a9f30   100a220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005659c0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX    7   cbc 000000001a396670   200b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005659c0     1 MTA
XXXX    b  173c 000000001a3f22b0   8009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005659c0     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
XXXX    6  1b2c 000000001a3f37e0   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005659c0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX    4   ca0 000000001a3f29c0   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005659c0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX    a   da0 000000001a3f5420   1009220 Enabled  0000000004120ba8:0000000004122ad8 00000000005659c0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX    9   b9c 000000001a3f4d10   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000005659c0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX    8  1194 000000001a3f4600   1009220 Enabled  0000000004134638:0000000004134b38 00000000005659c0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
0:009> **~1**
        ^ Illegal thread error in '~1'
0:009> **~1s**
        ^ Illegal thread error in '~1s'
0:009> **~**
.  9  Id: fd8.e24 Suspend: 0 Teb: 000007ff`ffef6000 Unfrozen
0:009> **~**
.  9  Id: fd8.e24 Suspend: 0 Teb: 000007ff`ffef6000 Unfrozen
0:009> **~#s;~clrstack**
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xa:
00000000`773115da c3              ret
            ^ Syntax error in '~#s;~clrstack'
0:009> **!eestack**
0:009> **~*k**

.  9  Id: fd8.e24 Suspend: 0 Teb: 000007ff`ffef6000 Unfrozen
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`1a8fe088 00000000`772e418b ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xa
00000000`1a8fe090 000007fe`f9ee8552 ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x9b
00000000`1a8fe0c0 000007fe`f9ee83e4 mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes+0x14a
00000000`1a8fe3b0 000007fe`f2ef8787 mscoreei!CLRRuntimeHostInternalImpl::ShutdownAllRuntimesThenExit+0x14
00000000`1a8fe3e0 000007fe`f2ef980c clr!EEPolicy::ExitProcessViaShim+0x88
00000000`1a8fe430 000007fe`f327cd38 clr!SafeExitProcess+0xdc
00000000`1a8fe6e0 000007fe`f30e8114 clr!EEPolicy::HandleFatalError+0x129
00000000`1a8fecc0 000007fe`f2ecb33c clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0xd51f4
00000000`1a8fecf0 000007fe`f2ecb2f2 clr!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerPhase2+0x2d
00000000`1a8fed40 000007fe`f2ecb1a1 clr!CLRVectoredExceptionHandler+0xaf
00000000`1a8fedb0 00000000`772da59f clr!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerShim+0x95
00000000`1a8fede0 00000000`772d8e42 ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers+0xa8
00000000`1a8fee50 00000000`77311278 ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x22
00000000`1a8ff530 000007fe`f2e35867 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0x2e
00000000`1a8ffaf0 000007fe`f30b5cab clr!WKS::gc_heap::background_sweep+0x5bd
00000000`1a8ffc50 000007fe`f2e33b56 clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x9f252
00000000`1a8ffca0 00000000`76bf652d clr!WKS::gc_heap::gc_thread_function+0xd3
00000000`1a8ffcd0 00000000`772ec521 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`1a8ffd00 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
0:009> **analyze -v**
Couldn't resolve error at 'nalyze -v'
0:009> **!analyze -v**
Last event: fd8.e24: Exit process 0:fd8, code 80131506
  debugger time: Fri Aug 17 18:52:01.744 2012 (GMT-6)
0:009> **!analyze -f**
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

Event is not an exception


Failure could not be analyzed

Last event: fd8.e24: Exit process 0:fd8, code 80131506
  debugger time: Fri Aug 17 18:52:01.744 2012 (GMT-6)
0:009> **.exr 1**
Cannot read Exception record @ 0000000000000001
0:009> **.exr 0**
Cannot read Exception record @ 0000000000000000
0:009> **!dumpstack**
OS Thread Id: 0xe24 (9)
Child-SP         RetAddr          Call Site
000000001a8fe088 00000000772e418b ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xa
000000001a8fe090 000007fef9ee8552 ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x9b
000000001a8fe0c0 000007fef9ee83e4 mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes+0x14a
000000001a8fe3b0 000007fef2ef8787 mscoreei!CLRRuntimeHostInternalImpl::ShutdownAllRuntimesThenExit+0x14
000000001a8fe3e0 000007fef2ef980c clr!EEPolicy::ExitProcessViaShim+0x88
000000001a8fe430 000007fef327cd38 clr!SafeExitProcess+0xdc
000000001a8fe6e0 000007fef30e8114 clr!EEPolicy::HandleFatalError+0x129
000000001a8fecc0 000007fef2ecb33c clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0xd51f4
000000001a8fecf0 000007fef2ecb2f2 clr!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerPhase2+0x2d
000000001a8fed40 000007fef2ecb1a1 clr!CLRVectoredExceptionHandler+0xaf
000000001a8fedb0 00000000772da59f clr!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerShim+0x95
000000001a8fede0 00000000772d8e42 ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers+0xa8
000000001a8fee50 0000000077311278 ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x22
000000001a8ff530 000007fef2e35867 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0x2e
000000001a8ffaf0 000007fef30b5cab clr!WKS::gc_heap::background_sweep+0x5bd
000000001a8ffc50 000007fef2e33b56 clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x9f252
000000001a8ffca0 0000000076bf652d clr!WKS::gc_heap::gc_thread_function+0xd3
000000001a8ffcd0 00000000772ec521 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
000000001a8ffd00 0000000000000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

I'm pretty much confused in WinDbg and just shooting in the dark hoping to get a CLR stack trace, but judging by the stack trace from the unmanaged code, WinDbg caught it after the fact.

Does anybody have any ideas on the cause and/or a fix for it?
Or any insight on where to go from here?

After the comment from Hans, here is my result for !VerifyHeap and the dump of the heap where it blew up.

```
0:000> !VerifyHeap
-verify will only produce output if there are errors in the heap
object 0000000002832a90: does not have valid MT
curr_object:      0000000002832a90
Last good object: 0000000002832a78
----------------
0:000> !do 0x2832a78
Free Object
Size:        24(0x18) bytes
0:000> dc 0x2832a78
00000000`02832a78  0055cd90 00000000 00000000 00000000  ..U.............
00000000`02832a88  0055cd90 00000000 000000b0 00000000  ..U.............
00000000`02832a98  000000a8 000007ff 00000000 00010000  ................
00000000`02832aa8  f2792140 000007fe 00453480 000007ff  @!y......4E.....
00000000`02832ab8  00000000 00010000 f2792140 000007fe  ........@!y.....
00000000`02832ac8  00453758 000007ff 00000000 00010000  X7E.............
00000000`02832ad8  f2792140 000007fe 00453a30 000007ff  @!y.....0:E.....
00000000`02832ae8  00000000 00010000 f2792140 000007fe  ........@!y.....
0:000> d
00000000`02832af8  004534f0 000007ff 00000000 00010000  .4E.............
00000000`02832b08  f2792140 000007fe 0045f2c0 000007ff  @!y.......E.....
00000000`02832b18  00000000 00010000 f2792140 000007fe  ........@!y.....
00000000`02832b28  004b1590 000007ff 000000d8 00000000  ..K.............
00000000`02832b38  ffffff28 ffffffff 00000000 000007ff  (...............
00000000`02832b48  00000000 00000000 f1db6728 000007fe  ........(g......
00000000`02832b58  00000064 00450053 0045004c 00540043  d...S.E.L.E.C.T.
00000000`02832b68  00560020 004c0041 00450055 00440020   .V.A.L.U.E. .D.
```

Comment: It bombs while running a garbage collection.  Which is typical, a common time to discover that the heap got corrupted.  You have no use for the stack trace, the corruption happened a while ago.  Very hard to debug, look for unmanaged code or bad pinvoke declarations first.  Disabling chunks of code and lots of unit tests are the best approaches to narrowing it down.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ran a !VerifyHeap command on the memory dump, and it came back stating an object does not have a valid MT. I updated my original post with some windbg output from where the heap got corrupted. Any insights?